# jQuery version conflict resolution with ASP.NET Server Control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, versioning, conflict, custom-server-controls

I am developing an ASP.NET server control that uses jQuery for some client side logic. I have embedded the jQuery file as a resource inside the control.

I don't want to restrict the application using the control to that specific version of jQuery and I want to keep using the version of jQuery that I have embedded.

I know about the noconflict method but the problem that i see with that is that i have no control over the order of the script tags on the page.

If the user's version of jQuery is included before mine than I'll end up overriding it before I can call noconflict.

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [`noConflict(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/):

```
var myJQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

The `true` parameter tells jQuery to release the `jQuery` symbol in addition to the `$` symbol. Just add this to the end of the jQuery.js file you're embedding in the control.

The jQuery script is smart about conflicts. The first thing it does is grab whatever the current value of both `$` and `jQuery` are and squirrel them away so it can restore them later if you ask it to. So if your script is loaded first, neither `$` nor `jQuery` will be defined and the new one can have them. If your script is loaded second, it *restores* the earlier `$` and `jQuery`.

**Example**:

Let's assume you're using the latest (v1.5.1), but the page author is using the older 1.4.4. Effectively, by tacking `var jq151 = jQuery.noConflict(true);` on the end of the 1.5.1 file, you're doing this:

```
<script src='jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>
<script>var jq151 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

...except it'd all be in one script tag. So two possibilities:

1) They go first:

```
<script src='jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>
<script src='jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>
<script>var jq151 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/icowo5)

2) You go first:

```
<script src='jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>
<script>var jq151 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script src='jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/icowo5/2)

Either way, both `jQuery` and `$` end up pointing to their 1.4.4 version, and `jq151` ends up pointing to your 1.5.1 version.

---

Perhaps slightly off-topic, but for anyone thinking this is a bit magical, it's actually really easy. :-) Here's a script that will redefine `foo`, but restore the previous definition if you ask it to:

```
// The script
(function() {
    var globalObject = this, // Or just use `window` on browsers
        oldfoo,
        ourfoo;

    oldfoo = globalObject.foo;
    ourfoo = globalObject.foo = {
        version: "new",
        restorePrevious: restorePrevious
    };

    function restorePrevious() {
        globalObject.foo = oldfoo;
        return ourfoo;
    }
})();
```

[Example with `foo` defined before the above](http://jsbin.com/ogize3)

[Example with `foo` defined after the above](http://jsbin.com/ogize3/2) (if you're wondering why this works despite `var foo` being *after* the script, [here's some reading](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html) on read up on poor, misunderstood `var`)

---

**About plug-ins**: You asked below about plug-ins. Plug-ins register themselves by assigning their features to properties on `jQuery.fn` and (in some cases) `jQuery`, like so:

```
jQuery.fn.makeFoo = function() {
};
```

With the above, you can access a `makeFoo` function on jQuery instances (e.g., `$('foo').makeFoo();`). A *well-written* plug-in will ensure that it plays nicely with both `noConflict()` and `noConflict(true)` by using this structure:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.makeFoo = function() {
        $(this).addClass("foo");
    };
})(jQuery);
```

...or one like it. (With the above, we'd *never* use `jQuery` to refer to jQuery within the function body. If we wanted to, we could add `var jQuery = $;` at the top.)

That defines an anonymous function and immediately calls it, passing in the current global value for `jQuery`. It receives that as a `$` *argument*, and so within the function the symbol `$` will *always* be the `jQuery` instance that it passed into itself. It can freely use `$` knowing that it refers the the version of jQuery on which it's registered.

An only somewhat well-written plug-in may assume that `jQuery` will always be the same (e.g., only plays nicely with `noConflict()` and not with `noConflict(true)`). You can fix those, though. If you run into one, make a copy of it and put

```
(function($) {
    var jQuery = $;
```

...at the top and

```
})(jQuery);
```

...at the bottom. 99% of the time, that will make it behave.

If you want to use plug-ins with your embedded jQuery instance, your best bet is to include them *in* your customized file. So the file contents become:

- The jQuery script
- (plug-in script)
- (plug-in script)
- ...
- Your `var jq151 = jQuery.noConflict(true);`

Comment: I don't think it restores what may have been the value of "$" before, as the OP seems to wish

Comment: @motionman95: That's *exactly* what it does, see the linked docs for details.

Comment: This is great. Seems to work exactly as i wanted. How do plugins behave in this case? Will they be available from both versions ?

Comment: @Ali: Unless the plug-ins know about your `jq151` (or whatever) symbol, they won't register themselves with that copy of jQuery, only the "main" copy on `jQuery`. If you have plug-ins you want to use with your copy, put them *in* your customised file, after the jQuery part and before your `noConflict` part. That lets them register themselves with `jQuery`, which you then release when they're done. Well-written plug-ins will then work. A poorly-written one may need some special attention.

Comment: @Ali: I've added a note about plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice solution: Don't use jQuery. At least - not at first. Use javascript to wait until all scripts have loaded, store the value of "$", and then inject jQuery in via script tag, and restore the previous value of "$".

Comment: It's not just `$`, it's `jQuery` too. Fortunately, jQuery itself does what you're suggesting (stores the old value before assigning the new value).